# Transpose n rows to n columns in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a requirement to transpose rows to column as shown below. The challenge here is I don't know the number of rows, it will be dynamic. Based on that I need to do a pivot in Redshift. Please help me with a solution.

Below is the example:

Source data

```
Material    Zipcode Volume  Week        
123 60007   10  May 2nd 2021        
123 60007   40  May 9th 2021        
123 60007   20  May 23rd 2021       
456 60007   10  May 16 2021     
456 60007   50  May 9th 2021
```

Target data expected

```
Pivoted data        Volume          
Material    Zipcode May 2nd 2021    May 9th 2021    May 16 2021 May 23rd 2021
123 60007   10  40  0   20
456 60007   0   50  10  0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Amazon Redshift does not have a pivot command. It is normally possible to PIVOT using some clever `CASE` statements, but that only works if you know how many columns you want to create.

You will probably need to write a [Stored Procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html), or do the logic outside of Redshift (eg query the rows, then construct a query that will use `CASE` to generate the desired output). I'm not even sure how you would write this logic as a Stored Procedure.